# issue in wp_localize_script

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-localize-script

I am initializing wp_localize_script after enqueueing scripts like that

```
wp_enqueue_script('main',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/mains.js','','1.1',true);
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));
```

but i am unable to get it in jquery file/code jquery code is

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on( 'click', '.page-numbers', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_pagination'
            },
            success: function( result ) {
                alert( result );
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

on clicking i am seeing the error ajaxpagination is not defined , what can be the possible solutions for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first param of `wp_localize_script` to same as the handle of your main script file.

`main` in this case.

Comment: awesome sir thanks ... one more thing if you have time ... i have changed this and now on click i am getting this error http://prntscr.com/nwbity

Comment: Have you registered your ajax handler with `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` action hooks, too?

Comment: you are awesome sir :) thanks for the very quick help ...

Comment: E.g. `add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_pagination', 'my_ajax_pagination_function' );`

Comment: yes sir all is ok now , moving towards next thing :)